# Ruby on Rails cannot bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

Ruby version: 2.1.5p273
Rails version: 4.2.0
Gem Version: 2.2.2
OS: Windows 7 x64

Hello, I am very very new to rails programming. I am trying to start learning, but cannot 
because of these problems.

- I created a rails app 
   I type: >rails new app
- I then navigate to the created folder
   I type:  >rails server
- It tells me 
  "Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems."
- I do so and it than tells me:
  "Make sure that 'gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.2.0' succeeds before bundling'"

after installing said gem I try bundle install again, but it than repeats the same error with a different gem.

```
""Make sure that 'gem install *random gem* -v '*random version*' succeeds before bundling'""
```

I hardly have any idea what I'm doing here. How can I get this server running?

Comment: Solved by using the following two commands: gem update --system, gem install bundler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by using the following two commands:
 gem update --system 
 gem install bundler

Answer (score 3):

i started to write an answer, and then saw you comment,

but for everyone out there who need an answer and didn't notice your comment:

Try this,

first run:

```
bundle update
```

and then try to `bundle install`

if its not working, install bundler:

```
gem install bundler
```

and now run `bundle install`