# Certificate failure and Windows10 gem version 2.4.5.1

Tags: windows, ssl, rubygems, certificate

I'm new to much of this:

My problem begins at the `rails new sample_app` stage of the installrails.com process.

it does its thing, getting to `run bundle install` and errors with "Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/."

I search and learn I must update certificates, as discussed here:  http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/

I learn at the above page that rubygems 2.4.x is broken for windows, and therefore no download exists to update my certificates.

So I try to update `$ gem update --system 2.6.7`  and this is what is returned:

Updating rubygems-update
ERROR:  Error installing rubygems-update:
        Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'rubygems-update (= 2.6.7)'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `version' for nil:NilClass

I keep trying to figure out how to do something so simple as uninstall my gem version 2.4.5.1 and install 2.6.7 but can't do it... my syntax?

I have also seen a workaround using these:
   `gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org/`
   `gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/`

But I don't understand how that helps with certificates or how it is a permanent solution!  I removed the secure source, and cannot reobtain it because of the same certificate error.  So now I am stuck with the http one.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Okay so I started fresh after posting the question.

I used the work around to bypass the certificate problem:

`gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org/`

`gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/`

This then allowed me to update my gem version.

`gem update --system`

Then I switched gem sources back:

`gem sources --remove http://rubygems.org/`

`gem sources -a https://rubygems.org/`

I ran into another problem when running `rails new sample_app` at the same place, bundle install.  I found the fix here: [Ruby on Rails cannot bundle install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729983/ruby-on-rails-cannot-bundle-install)

my command was `gem install bundler`

then I was able to successfully create the sample app.  Looking forward to the next problem!